# cannot install chaincode using hurley hyperledger fabric

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, convector, hurley

when i run hurl install "name-of-the-chain" node i receive an error saying "Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Failed to pull hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:latest: API error (404)" , I've tried to change it in the core.yaml file but still same issue

Answer (score 2):

`latest` tag has been deprecated since there are two `hyperledger fabric` versions and hence `latest` tag is misleading. You can set `CORE_CHAINCODE_BUILDER=hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:Version_Info` in peer environment variables and set `version_info` to your specific version

`fabric` team fixed this issue in `v1.4.8` and belowis the
**snippet from github change logs**

```
This change ensures that v1.4.x peers using the default
configuration will pull the latest v1.4 fabric-ccenv image from dockerhub to build chaincode,
if the local fabric-ccenv image is not found
```

link: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v1.4.8